# TableView salvando as linhas selecionadas

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let dias = ["Segunda-feira","Terça-feira","Quarta-feira","Quinta-feira","Sexta-feira","Sábado","Domingo"]      

    var selecionados = [Bool]()

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dias.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dias[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var selectedItem = indexPath
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        {

        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
        else{
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }
        print(selectedItem.row)
}
```

Bom quero criar um 'checkbox' escolhi fazer isso através do Tableview, porém estou com duas dificuldades, toda vez que eu seleciono e desmarco a linha ele da um print, não sei se está correto, porém eu queria adicionar as linhas selecionadas em um variável e salvar com o userDefaults, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Tem algumas opções pra você fazer isso, mas um array de Bool acho que não vai te ajudar....

Eu acho que a melhor forma é você ter um dicionário [Dia da Semana : Bool]. Na sua viewDidLoad, você inicializa esse dicionário colocando todos os valores para false... algo assim:

```
for dia em dias {
  selecionados[dia] = false
}
```

Já na sua função didSelectRowAt, se estava desmarcado e o usuário marcou, você faz `selecionados[dias[indexPath.row]] = true`, caso contrário, você atribui `false`de novo.

Agora... Nesta amostra de código, eu não estou vendo `UITableViewDelegate` e nem `UITableViewDataSource`. Só confere se no seu projeto eles estão lá. ;)